# ¿como hacer en php para guardar un registro que en su tabla esta relacionada con otra?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengos 2 tablas que se llaman bancos y tarjetas, pero la tabla tarjeta esta relacionada con bancos por el campo idbancos?; la estructura de la tabla tarjetas es;
Campos     Tipo_dato   Tamaño     Indice     Autoincremento
Idtarjetas     integer         11             PK           si
Idbancos     integer          11             FK
Tarjeta         Varchar         100
Estado         Enum('0','1')

Tengo la siguiente función registrar_tarjeta pero no guarda

```html
public function registrar_tarjeta($idtarjeta,$idbanco,$tarjeta,$est){

         $conectar=parent::conexion();
         parent::set_names();

         if($_POST["est"]=="0"){

             $estado=1;

           } else {

             $estado=0;
           }

         
         require_once("Bancos.php");
            $banco = new Bancos();
            
            $datos= $banco->get_nombre_banco_id($idbanco);

            foreach ($datos as $row) {

                  $codibanco = $row["idbanco"];
                  $nombanco = $row["banco"];

            }
                  

                  // Guarda los datos en banco

            $sql = "insert into tarjetas 
                    values(null,?,?,?);";

            
            $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(1, $codibanco);
            $sql->bindValue(2, $tarjeta);
            $sql->bindValue(3, $estado);
            $sql->execute();

        }
```

Pero al tratar de guardar no guarda nada, estoy usando bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras ,ayudame con esta solución si sabes

Comment: @David, ayúdame con esta solución si sabes si tienes experiencia en desarrollo web en php y uso de tablas relacionales con un proyecto que hayas realizado

Comment: @Marcos buenas tardes!; soy de Ecuador soy Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo ayúdame con esta solución para guardar los datos en una tabla relacional en php si tienes experiencia en php

Comment: @phpMyGuel buenas tardes!; soy Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo desde Ecuador me ayúdas con esta consulta para guardar los datos en una tabla relacional en php

Comment: ¿Como se puede ingresar un registro en mysql en una tabla que esta relacionada con otra tabla pero a nivel de código pero en php cuando?; usando en un proyecto que usa bootstrap con javascript, su ayuda en esta consulta se los agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un [Typo](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/typo), no es `=>` es `->`, ya que son propiedades y funciones de una clase.

En lugar de:

```php
   $sql=$conexion=>prepare($sql);
   $sql=>bindValue(1, $idbancos);
   $sql=>bindValue(2, $tarjeta);
   $sql=>bindValue(3, $estado);
   $sql=>execute();
```

Seria:

```php
   $sql=$conexion->prepare($sql);
   $sql->bindValue(1, $idbancos);
   $sql->bindValue(2, $tarjeta);
   $sql->bindValue(3, $estado);
   $sql->execute();
```

Comment: ¡Gracias!, y si graba en tablas relacionales has probado esto?

Comment: Yo no he probado nada, el typo es un error que se ve a simple vista. A tablas relacionadas te refieres a un ["FOREIGN KEY"](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)? Por que si es así, la relación entre las tablas se debe hacer al crear la tabla, no cuando ingresas un dato.

Comment: Gracias @Alex Garcia por tu ayuda

Comment: Si te fue de utilidad y dio con la respuesta, márcala como aceptada, le ayudará al sitio a mantener su buena salud :D Gracias.